# Get Notification received time in Android

Tags: android, time, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase to push notification from server to a specific android device. I want to get time when notification is received (device's local time not server time). How can I get that?

Because I have to show a timer with respect to that time so that is why I need that exact time when notification received on that device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think an effective way would be **use the Calendar class in your onMessageReceived()** somewhat like this :

```
Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
```

Comment: I thought that there would be any built in method....but as you mentioned to use onMessageReceived().....so I put the Millis time in extras to get inside the intent by using onMessageReceived(). Thanks for help :)

Comment: Also, remember to send **only DATA** payload via your appserver or your onMessageReceived will not be triggered when app is in background or killed and in that case it will be bit tricky to track the time you receive notification.

Comment: Damn! you are right @Nishant I am unable to get time when app is closed. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just make sure your json payload is sending only *DATA* to fcm server and you will be good to go.

Comment: {
  "notification":{
    "body": "Notification Message",
    "title": "Notification Title",
    "sound": "default",
    "priority": "high",
    "click_action": "ACTIVITY_MAIN_MAP"
  },
  "data":{
    "id": 2,
    "missedRequests": 5
  },
  "to": "fcmkey"
}

This is what I am sending....Does it need any modifications?

Comment: Yes.. Remove **notification** payload completely. Send only data and handle it in onMessageReceived()

Comment: Instead of relying on firebase inbuilt notification builder. You will have to have your own notification builder implemented in **onMessageReceived** and send **only DATA** only then you will be able to intercept exact time in onMessageReceived()

Comment: Thanks @Nishant for all the help :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use this firebase function in the `onMessageReceived()` method:

```
Long time = remoteMessage.getSentTime();
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: For kotlin, it would be remoteMessage.sentTime

Answer (score 1):

```
String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());
```

Write this line in your service class which extends FirebaseMessagingService . 
The  function is looked like

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());
Log.d("time",currentDateTimeString);
    createNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }
```